# How to label rivers in openlayers

Tags: openlayers

I'm using openlayers 4 to render rivers as shown on the screenshot below (map zoom level 7) and would like to display river names along the lines. The river features are openstreetmap waterway=river ways served by geoserver to a vectore layer.

The features are styled like this, but the lines are so curvy that the names are almost never rendered.

```
var styles = {
'river_lines': new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'blue',
        width: 1.25
    })
}),
'river_labels': new ol.style.Style({
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        text: '',
        font: '15px sans-serif',
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'white'
        }),
        placement: 'line',
        maxAngle: 0.15
    })
})
};
```

I've tried replace the geometry of the label style with a simplified one but it did not change anything.

```
styles.river_labels.setGeometry(feature.getGeometry().simplify(0.9));
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally solved it by merging OSM waterway=river ways into one way and adding "overflow: true" parameter to the label style.

[image]